# How to apply generic constraint to accept multi level of inheritance C#

Tags: c#, .net, oop, multiple-inheritance, generic-constraints

I am looking for a way to support multi level of inheritance for generic type constraint.

**Common generic interface**

```
public interface ICommon<T>
{
    T OrignalData {get;set;}
    string ChangeJson {get;set;}
    T Merged {get;set;}
    void Inject();
}
```

**Common base class implements ICommon**

```
public class Base <T>: ICommon<T>
{
    public T OrignalData {get;private set;}
    public string ChangeJson {get;set;}
    public T Merged {get;private set;}
    public void Inject(T orignal)
    {
        if (orignal == null)
            return;
       
        var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
        {
            ObjectCreationHandling = ObjectCreationHandling.Auto
        };
        dynamic merged = orignal.Clone();
        JsonConvert.PopulateObject(this.ChangeJson, merged, settings);
        this.Merged  = merged;
        this.Orignal = orignal;
    }
}
```

**Department class inherits Base class**

```
public class Deparment : Base<Deparment>
{
}
```

**OrgnizationDepartment class inherits Deparment**

```
public class OrgnizationDepartment : Deparment
{

}
```

**class View expect ICommon must implement on passed calls**

```
public class View<T> where T : ICommon<T>
{
   //This class is totally dynamic to visualize any json data along with  old and new value of requested json for any class like department or org..
}
```

**Test**

```
public class Test
{
    public void TestConstraint()
    {
        //No error 
        var deptView = new View<Deparment>();

        //Error as Base not directly implemented on OrgnizationDepartment 
        var orgView = new View<OrgnizationDepartment>();
    }
}
```

how do I define my constraint that should support for multi level as well.

Comment: Your problem is nothing to do with the constraints really... Its the fact that `OrganizationDepartment` is a `Base<Department>` and **not** a `Base<OrganizationDepartment>`

Comment: @pinkfloydx33, how can correct it?

Comment: You _could_ have `Department` and `OrganizationDepartment` implement the interface and change from `Base` class inheritance to composition. As is, it doesn't make sense anyway. Any method that OrganizationDepartment inherits from Department, that uses T is locked in to Department, not OrganizationDepartment.

Comment: ok, I have to call common methods from both Department and OrganizationDepartment individual members those are implemented by ICommon.

Comment: _" implemented by ICommon"_ - no they are not. They may be _defined_ by ICommon. (Or do you have default implementations?) Maybe add one or two example methods. Then we can advise more clearly.

Comment: And another question would be: Do you _really_ need `ICommon` to be generic?

Comment: @Fildor, yes I have added one basic functionality in ICommon(updated post), there are some other functionality also in my actual code, the situation I asked in my post is some of hypothetical case, all other are simple like Department one.

Comment: Hm, your Base class does not seem to actually implement that interface.

Comment: Have a look at this: https://dotnetfiddle.net/Rv5HSQ Is that somewhat a direction you could use?

Comment: thanks @Fildor, solution you provided helps me a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*One* way out of this would be "composition over inheritance".

Here is a naive example, that is still relatively close to your code:

```
using System;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        //No error 
        var deptView = new View<Deparment>();

        //Formerly Error 
        var orgView = new View<OrgnizationDepartment>();
    }
}

public interface ICommon<T> where T : ICloneable
{
    // returns a tuple
    (T,T,string) Inject(T original, string change);
}

public class Base <T>: ICommon<T> where T : ICloneable
{
   // we can reuse this...
   private readonly JsonSerializerSettings  settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
        {
            ObjectCreationHandling = ObjectCreationHandling.Auto
        };

    public (T,T,string) Inject(T original, string change)
    {
        if (original is null)
            return default;
        
        // this forces T to implement ICloneable ... just saying...
        dynamic merged = original.Clone();
        
        JsonConvert.PopulateObject(change, merged, settings);
        return (original, merged, change);
    }
}

public class Deparment : ICloneable, ICommon<Deparment>
{
    // could also be created in ctor. Maybe use Ctor injection.
    private readonly Base<Deparment> common = new Base<Deparment>();
    public object Clone(){return this;} // this is of course nonsense. Clone properly! I did this to avoid dotnetfiddle screaming at me.
    public (Deparment, Deparment, string) Inject(Deparment original, string change){
        return common.Inject(original, change);
    }
}

public class OrgnizationDepartment : ICloneable, ICommon<OrgnizationDepartment>
{
    private readonly Base<OrgnizationDepartment> common = new Base<OrgnizationDepartment>();
    public object Clone() {return this;}
    public (OrgnizationDepartment, OrgnizationDepartment, string) Inject(OrgnizationDepartment original, string change){
        return common.Inject(original, change);
    }
}
```